# ¿Por qué me da Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number, en la consola?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Estoy tratando de hacer que una variable php se envíe a una database a través de AJAX pero al ejecutar el código de php e imprimirlo en la variable me da el siguiente error en la consola:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Dejo por aquí los codes ^^
Javascript + AJAX:

```
    <script> 



const badip = <?php echo $badip;?>;
//conditional in case ipqualityscore detects fraud ip.
if (badip === 100) {

var data_ip = <?php require_once './assets/php/ddos/fluct.php'; echo $ip;   ?>;

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./assets/php/ddos/action.php",
                    data: { data_ip: data_ip  }
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    console.log("Los datos que se recibieron: " + msg);
                });


}


</script>
```

fluct.php Code:

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function getUserIP() {
    if( array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',')>0) {
            $addr = explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            return trim($addr[0]);
        } else {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}

$ip = getUserIp();

?>
```

action.php CODE

```
if($conn){

$data_ip = $_POST['data_ip'];
        /* crear una sentencia preparada */
        $insertarDatos =  "INSERT INTO hehe(data_ip) VALUES(?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertarDatos);
        if ($stmt) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$data_ip);
            /* ejecutar la consulta */
            $stmt->execute();
            $msgOutput="Filas insertadas: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
            /* cerrar sentencia */
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            $msgOutput="Error preparando la consulta: ".$conn->error;
        }
        /* cerrar conexión */
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        $msgOutput="Error, no se pudo conectar a la base de datos: ".$conn->connect_error;
    }
} else {
    $msgOutput="No se postearon los datos correctamente";
}
echo $msgOutput;
```

Comment: El error que lo hace.

Comment: Si el error lo data_ip. Si el valor que resive data_ip es numérico está bien pero si el valor que resive es string tienes que encerrar con comillas el php

Comment: @gabriel Hola! A qué parte del código te refieres? Para ubicarme mejor

Answer (score 1):

Aquí estás asignando la IP a la variable data_ip:

```
var data_ip = <?php require_once './assets/php/ddos/fluct.php'; echo $ip;   ?>;
```

Pero no estás entrecomillando el valor, si fuera un número te serviría, pero la IP es una cadena (formada de dígitos separados por puntos). Por eso, tienes que entre comillarla. Además, te recomiendo que no pongas por medio el require_once, ofusca el código, déjalo más claro:

```
<?php require_once './assets/php/ddos/fluct.php'; ?>

var data_ip = '<?php echo $ip; ?>';
```

Otra cosilla es que aquí estás indicando que el parámetro $data_ip es un entero:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",$data_ip);
```

Pero no lo es, es una cadena. En vez de 'i', tienes que indicarle 's', para que espere una cadena, y la trate como tal a la hora de construir la instrucción SQL:

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $data_ip);
```

Comment: ¡Hola! He modificado lo que me has dicho pero aún así me sigue saliendo el mismo error en la consola. Voy a actualizar el code

Comment: Hola, me costaba ver la causa del error porque no tenía claro si era un error PHP o Javascript. Analizando mejor el código, vi lo que apuntaba gabriel en su comentario, que, aunque no es muy claro, por ahí iban los tiros. He retocado la respuesta, mira a ver ahora.